# Array with three major objects compare

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

i have a problem when im trying to create a dynamic rendering logic. I would like to render these object values based on the area-value, but cant seem to get the logic for the comparison just right. Dont really know if i have written the objects quite right?
Im writing in react with typescript hope anyone got an answer :D

```js
const data = [
  {
      Area: 'Avenyn', 
      Bar: [
        {
          title: 'Yaki-da', 
          image: '', 
          info: 'fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf'
        }, 
        {
          title: 'Lounge', 
          image: '', 
          info: 'fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf'
        }, 
        {
          title: 'Hardrock-cafe', 
          image: '', 
          info: 'fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf'
        },
        {
          title: 'Valand', 
          image: '', 
          info: 'fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf'
        },
      ], 
  },
  {
    Area: 'Hisingen', 
    Bar: [
      {
        title: 'Ölstugan', 
        image: '', 
        info: 'fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf'
      }, 
    ],
  }
]

const test = data.map((value) => value.Bar)
  const bars: any = []
  
  const arrayPush =  () => {
    for(let i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
      test[i].map((value) => bars.push(value.title))
    }
  }
    arrayPush()
    return (
      <div style={rootStyle}>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/"> 
              {data.map((value) => 
                  <ContentItem title={value.Area} key={value.Area}/>
              )}
            </Route>
             {data.map((value) => 
              <Route path={'/' + value.Area}>
                {bars.map((value: string) => <BarNavigation id={value} key={value}/>)}
              </Route>
            )} 
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me what you needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you would like to get a list of Areas, each with their bars underneath?

You can embed a second map within the first to achieve this:

```
            {data.map((value) => 
            <div>
                <ContentItem title={value.Area} key={value.Area}/>
                {value.Bar.map(bar=> 
                    <BarNavigation id={bar.title} key={bar.title}/>)}
            </div>
            )}
```

The full block would look something like:

```
const data = [
    {
        Area: 'Avenyn', 
        Bar: [
          {
            title: 'Yaki-da', 
            image: '', 
            info: 'fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf'
          }, 
          {
            title: 'Lounge', 
            image: '', 
            info: 'fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf'
          }, 
          {
            title: 'Hardrock-cafe', 
            image: '', 
            info: 'fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf'
          },
          {
            title: 'Valand', 
            image: '', 
            info: 'fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf'
          },
        ], 
    },
    {
      Area: 'Hisingen', 
      Bar: [
        {
          title: 'Ölstugan', 
          image: '', 
          info: 'fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf'
        }, 
      ],
    }
  ]
  
  const myPage = () => {
      return (
        <div style={rootStyle}>
          <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/"> 
                {data.map((value) => 
                <div>
                    <ContentItem title={value.Area} key={value.Area}/>
                    {value.Bar.map(bar=> 
                        <BarNavigation id={bar.title} key={bar.title}/>)}
                </div>
                )}
              </Route>
               {data.map((value) => 
                <Route path={'/' + value.Area}>
                  {bars.map((value: string) => <BarNavigation id={value} key={value}/>)}
                </Route>
              )} 
          </Switch>
        </div>
      );
  }
```